# Jquery Animation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I put together a jQuery animation for a menu background. The menu has a dropdown and when you hover over the menu the animation kicks in, but the dropdown starts to act all wonky.  Pretty new to jquery so not sure why this is doing that.

I added a div (menu-bg) with absolute position to change height on hover inside the menu.

Here is my javascript controlling the animation:

```
 $('.navbar-nav >li > a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().next().animate({
            height: "60px"
        }, {
            easing: "swing",
            queue: true,
            duration: 400
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().next().animate({
            height: "0px"
        }, {
            easing: "swing",
            queue: true,
            duration: 200
        });
    });
```

Here is a link to the site to view the actual issue, you will notice it when you hover over home.

http://bratworks.com/static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following changes in your code got the job done:

Inside of **init.js** around line 15 remove the 200 millisecond delay from the dropdown menu fadeOut().

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeOut();
```

I re-wrote your hover function to target the *li*'s instead of the *a*, it looked like there was some kind of conflict there:

```
$('.navbar-nav > li').on({
 mouseenter: function() {;
    $(this).find('.menu-bg').animate({ height: "60px" });
  }, 
 mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.menu-bg').animate({ height: "0px" });
   }
 });
```

And finally, I overwrote the CSS that was creating that 5px margin gap on the .dropdown-menu:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top:0px!important;
}
```

There you go! Please let me know if you'd like me to expand on anything?

Comment: Awesome! This worked for the most part, had to make a couple changes to hand the mobile menu.  One question, why did you change the hover function?  Was I using the hover function incorrectly?

Comment: The hover method binds handlers to the mouseenter and mouseleave events - there's not really a difference, your hover function is fine! I think I was experimenting and just forgot to change it back. :) If my answer is satisfactory, I'd appreciate it if you gave me the vote too. Have a great week!

Comment: Great! Thanks, I unfortunately can't vote, but once I receive level 15 I will make sure to comeback and vote.  I did mark it correct though. Again thanks.